# Should I set Math.PI in a variable

Tags: javascript, performance

If I have multiple uses of `Math.PI` in a JavaScript function, is it better (performance-wise) to declare a new local variable for it or to just keep accessing it through the `Math` object?

Comment: The difference will likely be so insignificant as to be nonexistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, assuming you're running your code in a modern compiler there will be no performance benefit in doing so. The compiler will be smart enough (At least SpiderMonkey (Firefox) JSC (Safari) and V8 (Chrome)*) to not care about this.

They will be as fast.

(*) IE's JS runtime is probably smart enough too but I can not verify this since it's not open source.

Comment: *Obligatory comment about premature optimization*

Comment: Agree with BenjaminGruenbaum, this is premature optimization here. BTW, @shakyjake you can test it on your own if you want: http://jsperf.com/math-pi-or-local-variable

Comment: @pomeh Thanks for the jsPerf link, as the answer suggests, there isn't any real gain - in fact it appears that Math.PI is faster for most cases, excluding FF31 (0.21% faster) and IE11 (2.67% faster).